# How to read a file using ByteArrayInputStream in java?

Tags: java, file-io, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I have created a file called`"output.txt"` using this code snippet.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    BitSet bitset = new BitSet();
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            bitset.set(i, false);
        }else{
            bitset.set(i, true);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    byte[] bs = bitset.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(bs);
    baos.writeTo(fout);
}
```

Now how do I read `"output.txt"` file and get my `byte[] bs` back? Can anyone give me code for that? I am having trouble writing `ByteArrayInputStream` code.

Thanks

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream is an in-memory stream to read from a byte array, you must use FileInputStream to read byte array from file

Comment: On the other hand, I have another question. How do I read the bits from my output.txt file instead of a byte?